# How to get Content on Post Method

Tags: android

I've used below code for `HttpPost`, Its execute successfully. But unable to see the response.I get `InputStream`. I want to know what are the contents in it.

I want to display as string format.How to do this.

```
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(requestURL);
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(params.length);

        for (int postValueCount = 0; postValueCount < params.length; postValueCount++)
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(params[postValueCount][0],params[postValueCount][1]));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.d("HttpPostRequest","URL : " + httppost.getRequestLine().getUri());
            Log.d("HttpPostRequest","Method : " + httppost.getRequestLine().getMethod());
            Log.d("HttpPostRequest","Parameters : " + nameValuePairs);
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            status = response.getStatusLine();

            if (status.getReasonPhrase().equals("OK")) {
                httpEntity=response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();               
                return in;
            } else {
                Log.d("Http Status", status.getReasonPhrase());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Yes InputStream is not visible entity, if you want to see then you have to convert it into `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Comment: hi @bartoszfilipowicz after print the result, i unable to parse, it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed

Comment: Store it in a String if you want to use it more than once. EntityUtils.toString(InputStream is) is cleaning up after itself, so once you read the entity it's consumed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i have used in a project of mine.

```
static String isToString(InputStream is) {
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line = "0";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error converting result " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: hi @bughi after print the result, i unable to parse, it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed

Comment: because the method closes the InputStream after it's done with it, you can no longer call methods on the is. What exactly are you trying do to?